# JPA spring boot inner join - with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hql

I'm trying to select with a inner join in one of my JPA repositories

**the query:**

```
@Query(value = "select wm.WagerIdentification, wm.BoardNumber, wm.MarkSequenceNumber, wm.MarkNumber," +
        " pt.CouponTypeIdentification, pt.WagerBoardQuickPickMarksBoard " +
        "from WagerBoard wb " +
        "inner join wb.listOfWagerMarks wm on wb.WagerIdentification = wm.WagerIdentification and wb.BoardNumber = wm.BoardNumber and wb.GameIdentification = wm.GameIdentification and wm.meta_IsCurrent = 1 " +
        "inner join wb.poolgameTransaction pt on (wb.TransactionIdentification = pt.TransactionIdentification and pt.meta_IsCurrent = 1)" +
        "where wb.meta_IsCurrent = 1")
List<Object[]> findAllTest();
```

**relations:**

PoolgameTransactions

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "poolgameTransaction")
private List<WagerBoard> ListOfWagers = new ArrayList<>();
```

WagerBoard

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "TransactionIdentification", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "meta_CreatedDate", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private PoolgameTransaction poolgameTransaction;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wagerBoard")
private List<WagerBoardMarks> listOfWagerMarks;
```

WagerBoardMarks

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "BoardNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "GameIdentification", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "WagerIdentification", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "meta_CreatedDate", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private WagerBoard wagerBoard;
```

**the error:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the condition from On.. to the where part:

```
select wm.WagerIdentification, wm.BoardNumber, wm.MarkSequenceNumber, wm.MarkNumber," +
        " pt.CouponTypeIdentification, pt.WagerBoardQuickPickMarksBoard " +
        "from WagerBoard wb " +
        "inner join wb.listOfWagerMarks wm 
        "inner join wb.poolgameTransaction pt
where wm.meta_IsCurrent = 1 and wb.meta_IsCurrent = 1
```

The other dependencies are implicitly embedded in the mapping configuration anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. - how can i get the values from the objects when i receive the data as a object array ?

firstObject.valueImLookingfor not working

Comment: Use getter/setters...you will need getters to do that

Comment: i have getters and setters in every entity class. but when i recive it as object[] it dosent recognize the values

Comment: If you want to keep your query as it is, you have to know what kind of data is behind each index and then cast to appropriate type

Comment: HEre is a good article on how to pack the projection straight to a certain POJO without the need to cast.. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_

Comment: thanks again - last question : if i want to add " order by 1,2,3,4 " in my HQL statement. Any pointers on implementing that ?

Comment: I dont think you can order by ordinal in JPQL.. you would have to use a native query for that and a database that supports it.. like Oracle. In your case i would stick to the column names in the list

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ON in your query.Try the following:

```
@Query(value = "select wm.WagerIdentification, wm.BoardNumber, wm.MarkSequenceNumber, wm.MarkNumber," +
    " pt.CouponTypeIdentification, pt.WagerBoardQuickPickMarksBoard " +
    "from WagerBoard wb " +
    "inner join wb.listOfWagerMarks wm where wb.WagerIdentification = wm.WagerIdentification and wb.BoardNumber = wm.BoardNumber and wb.GameIdentification = wm.GameIdentification and wm.meta_IsCurrent = 1 " +
    "inner join wb.poolgameTransaction pt where (wb.TransactionIdentification = pt.TransactionIdentification and pt.meta_IsCurrent = 1)" +
    "where wb.meta_IsCurrent = 1")
List<Object[]> findAllTest();
```