# JPA Query left outer join loses elements

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

The mysql query with left outer join is:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM entity1 as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity2 as b
ON a.val = b.val AND b.active = true;
```

The result is a list with all entities of entity1 where entity2 is set when its active value is true, otherwise the entity2 class is null:

Due to the path problem in JPA ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473033/jpa-left-join-2-tables-without-association)) i have built a relation with outer join in JPA:

```
SELECT  new wrapper(a, b) FROM Entity1 a 
LEFT JOIN a.entity2 b 
WHERE b IS NULL OR b.active = true
```

Where the entity1 and entity2 are simplified to:

```
class Entity1 {
    long id;
    Set<Entity2> entity2;
}

class Entity2 {
    long id;
    boolean active;
}
```

Now i have the following result with the jpa query:

- if the Set of Entity2 is empty, entity2 is set to null
- if the active value of Entity2 is true, Entity1 and Entity2 are set correctly
- if the active value is false, there is no entry of Entity1.

This is not the expected behaviour of a left outer join.

Here is some easy overview:
[image]

Comment: Why not use `left join a.entity2 b on b.active = true`.

Comment: Because i get an error: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements. This post suggest to use where instead of on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42411712/3604955

Comment: Such a query works fine here. Are you using an old version of Hibernate?

Comment: I'm using the inbuild hibernate version of wildfly 10:
"The WildFly JPA subsystem implements the JPA 2.1 container-managed requirements. Deploys the persistence unit definitions, the persistence unit/context annotations and persistence unit/context references in the deployment descriptor. JPA Applications use the Hibernate (version 5) persistence provider, which is included with WildFly."

Comment: One more thing to your version with the "on"... i fixed some other error and now get following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'votes2_.APP_USER' in 'on clause'

It seems, hibernate cannot resolve the set correctly ...

Comment: *** i mean .ACTIVE not APP_USER ***